# cutting content in TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

when write content in arabic inside TextView first word in each line will cutting!!

this problem happen only when i set typeface to TextView!

[image: cuttig]

here my xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/articleTEXT"

    />
```

note: content will retrieve from SQLite Database.

Comment: try adding padding may be it help

Comment: Isn't arabic "backwards" compared to english? You need text direction don't you?

Comment: ^ Good catch @BobbyDigital

Comment: i tried text direction, no thing change, still cutting

Comment: I guess it is an emulator related problem, try running it on an actual device. Sometimes it happens with the emulator.

Comment: yes try Right padding.

Comment: You have set the gravity of textview to right......

Answer (score 1):

It will work,add padding in linear layout and take width of textview match parent.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/articleTEXT"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try placing this in your LinearLayout or TextView:

```
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
 >
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/articleTEXT"

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity to right in your textview and then set paddingRight to 20dp.

Or just put `padding=30dp` in your linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_margin="5dp">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/articleTEXT"
    android:padding="5dp"
/>
```